# String after and before character

Tags: r, regex, substring

I have this string

```
x = "Hello   how are    you Peter /"
```

And I would like to get only

```
x = "Peter"
```

I would like to find patter that extract only word after "you" and before "/" (exluded)

I would like to use something like

```
x = sub(" you*/.", "", x)
```

But I dont know how to make the pattern correctly.

Comment: try "(?<=you).*?(?=,)" and perl = TRUE. These are look behind and look ahead.

Comment: I edit my post and tried "(?<=you).*?(?=/)" and perl = TRUE                                     
 x = sub("(?<=you).*?(?=/)","", x, perl = T) but it exluded word Peter

Comment: I was thinking `str_extract(x, "(?<=you).*?(?=/)")`. thats my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(stringr)
str_match(x, "you\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\/")[, 2]
#[1] "Peter"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
gsub(".*you (.*) /$", "\\1", x)
```

Answer (score 1):

With lookahead and lookbehind:

```
library(stringr)
x = "Hello   how are    you Peter /"
str_extract(x,"(?<=you )\\w+(?= /)")
[1] "Peter"
```

If you want to be a bit more robust to spaces (if there is or not a space after the name for example, the example above will not work):

```
str_extract(x,"(?<=you)[\\w ]+(?=/)") %>% 
trimws()
```